# Redirecting all pages under a certain directory to a single file

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I want to redirect all pages under a certain directory to a single file, like so:

- `/dir/a` → `/dir/new`
- `/dir/b` →  `/dir/new`
- `/dir/new` →  `/dir/new`

With the straightforward

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/dir/ http://example.com/dir/new
```

I get a redirect loop, since /dir/new redirects to itself. I replaced it with a regular expression

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/dir/($|[^n]|n$|n[^e]|ne$|ne[^w]|new.) http://example.com/dir/new
```

which matches all URLs except the desired one. This works, but it's obviously the 'wrong' way to do it. What's a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`RedirectMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) doesn't redirect all pages under a certain directory *to a single file*:

> Then any request beginning with *`URL-path`* will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target *`URL`*. Additional path information beyond the matched *`URL-path`* will be appended to the target URL.

That is, a request for `/dir/a/blah` would get redirected to `/dir/new/blah`, not to `/dir/new` as you said you wanted.

As a solution, I suggest using [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $0 !=/dir/new
RewriteRule ^/dir/.* /dir/new [R]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're looking for a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):
path starting with `/dir/` and not followed by `new$`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/dir/(?!new$) http://example.com/dir/new
```